# Broken buttons colors [contrast]?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review

Today I noticed another strange colors on Unix.SE buttons here and on Meta. There is not enough contrast in any of them, examples:

[image: post question]
[image: post answer]

Previous colors/gradient were fine. Similar issue appeared week ago on AskUbuntu ([my meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15063/redesigned-disabled-buttons-in-review-are-hard-to-distinguish)). Not sure if it is the same issue, but it might be related. Buttons also appear in reviews, but I don't have any available at this time. Disabled button might look a bit different.

The text is really hard to read and when hovered, it is not much better (you can try bellow on the button).

**Edit**: Review queues are even more funny. Disabled buttons are not even shown:

[image: review]

**Edit2**: After fix, gradient is here, but the contrast on meta is still ... would say not sufficient:

[image: meta.unix]

<sup>Do I have to also add a kitten to have it fixed?</sup>

Comment: Agree that this is a regression...

Comment: Yes, this. The same problem occurs in the mod flag-handling page. The buttons are much harder to read and more tiring on the eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. Looking into this further, the button wasn't displaying correctly on Unix.SE or Meta.Unix. A background gradient should have been applied, but wasn't. This was because the gradient wasn't being applied to `input` correctly.

This has been corrected. Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

1. Okay another push has been made to darken the buttons on meta to
   increase the contrast.
2. Thanks again for posting this bug. It helped me uncover another bug which affected almost the entire Stack Exchange network. Kudos!

Comment: seems to be working on Unix. But this color on Meta (the black buttons [Add Comment]) seems to be still too light.

Comment: @Jakuje The buttons on meta are gray for you, correct?

Comment: I am not a designer, but I heard about some rule of contrast between text and background. :) I added screenshot to the question how it looks here. I would say that it would be nice to have a bit more contrast in some way it possible ;)

Comment: @Jakuje Updated

Comment: Thank you! This looks better for me.